# Alternative ways to step up voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transformer, preamp, voltage-amplification

I want to drive an EOM crystal at 20 MHz for phase modulation. I recently bought a step up RF transformer (1:4 turns ratio), but it's not working fine above 2 MHz. I tried winding a transformer myself on a toroidal ferrite core, but the cores don't seem to work properly at such high frequencies, they start attenuating once I enter the MHz regime. Are there alternative methods to facilitate stepping up voltage? Power requirement: 1-2 W. I have been thinking of using voltage preamps or power op-amps, but not sure of these yet.

Comment: What does 'EOM' mean? What frequency range needs to be stepped up, and how much attenuation is acceptable?

Comment: I'm suspecting it's not Original Equipment Manufacturer misspelled, but Electro Optic Modulation.

Comment: We need some more details. From what I understand you use the 20 MHz signal of the crystal to drive a RF transformer, and from that you want a 1-2 W 20 MHz transmission signal? Any schematic would be helpful.

Comment: @BruceAbbott 'EOM' here means Electro-Optic Modulator. The frequency range of 15-25 MHz needs to be stepped up. 1 dB attenuation is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell input impedance is more or less a large capacitance, your first job is to make it look resistive. This makes the drive amplifier easier to specify and design.

Design a lowpass LC ladder filter with an infinite output impedance (good filter design tools will let you choose one port with zero and infinite impedances, as well as a finite impedance). This infinite Z port will have a shunt capacitor there. Design the filter bandwidth to cover at least your operating range, and the filter impedance so that this final C is as large or larger than the C of your load. Now 'absorb' the load C into the filter C by reducing the filter C by the load capacitance.

Now have another crack at amplifiers. There are some quite impressive video amplifiers and fast opamps around. With a resistive load to drive, you'll find that RF transformers behave better as well.